# Export Full Catalog button

Tags: magento2, catalog, export

How do I enable the Export Full Catalog button or similar option on this page that does not appear in my installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Not recommended:**

You can add this in your `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`:

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <!-- other codes -->
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <!-- other codes -->
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
```

The export option will appear but when exporting it throws an error.

By default, this button is not available. I think Magento doesn't want us to allow to have this functionality here because it may impact performance.

**Recommended:**

There is an export feature in `System > Export` which will allow you to export the products. Check the image below. In order for it to work, make sure your crons are running.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The label alone if it generates an error, we have to send it parameters to avoid the error. I'm still wondering what it's like...